# joining multiple tables on common attributes with disjoint rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multiples tables which need to be joined on multiple common attributes such the different attributes can be shown in a single table.

table1

```
+--------+---------+-------+--------+
|  make  |  model  | year  |  kms   |
+--------+---------+-------+--------+
| toyota | corolla |  1999 |  25000 |
| toyota |  camry  |  2002 |  50000 |
+--------+---------+-------+--------+
```

table2

```
+--------+---------+-------+---------+
|  make  |  model  | year  | mileage |
+--------+---------+-------+---------+
| toyota | corolla |  1999 |      20 |
| toyota |  qualis |  2004 |      25 |
+--------+---------+-------+---------+
```

table3

```
+--------+----------+-------+-------+
|  make  |  model   | year  | color |
+--------+----------+-------+-------+
| toyota |  camry   |  2002 | blue  |
| toyota |  rav4    |  2006 | green |
+--------+----------+-------+-------+
```

I'm doing the following to join the results

```
select 
    * from table1 as a
    full join table2 as b
    using (make, model, year)
    full join table3 as c
    using (make, model, year)
```

What I need is a table like below.

```
+--------+---------+-------+-------+----------+--------+
|  make  |  model  | year  |  kms  |  mileage |  color |
+--------+---------+-------+-------+----------+--------+
| toyota | corolla |  1999 | 25000 |       20 |        |
| toyota |  camry  |  2002 | 50000 |          |  blue  |
| toyota |  qualis |  2004 |       |       25 |        |
| toyota |  rav4   |  2006 |       |          | green  |
+--------+---------+-------+-------+----------+--------+
```

However I get results with the `make,model,year` duplicated with some empty value for some rows.

How do I go about getting the required. Note that, for the real data set I'm working with, there are 5 `common attributes` per table and around 20-40 `different attributes` per table.

Comment: My instincts would be to test using the complete join syntax instead of relying on `USING`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicates could be due to the full join you are using. Change those to left joins as given below:

```
SELECT
A.MAKE, A.MODEL, A.YEAR, T1.KMS, T2.MILEAGE, T3.COLOR
FROM
(SELECT MAKE, MODEL, YEAR FROM TABLE1 UNION 
SELECT MAKE, MODEL, YEAR FROM TABLE2 UNION
SELECT MAKE, MODEL, YEAR FROM TABLE3) A
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T1 
ON T1.MAKE = A.MAKE AND T1.MODEL = A.MODEL AND T1.YEAR = A.YEAR
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T2.MAKE = A.MAKE AND T2.MODEL = A.MODEL AND T2.YEAR = A.YEAR
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 T3
ON T3.MAKE = A.MAKE AND T3.MODEL = A.MODEL AND T3.YEAR = A.YEAR;;
```

Comment: this may not work as the table2 will have new `make, model, year` combination.

Comment: this works for the example in the OP. Also see the note I added, in the real data I have around 5 common cols and additionally 20 to 40 cols unique to each of 10 tables to be joined - for that scenario is there a way to specify the common columns only - that without having to specify each column name like `T1.KMS, T2.MILEAGE, T3.COLOR` - in my real data this would be 200 to 400 attributes in the query - basically I'm asking is there a way to simplify this to specify join `all cols other than the common cols` which would come from the table created by via `UNION`

Comment: Never came across a workaround for that. As far as I know, we can either use select * for all columns or select specific fields(comma separated). I would copy the list of columns from table description, process it by introducing commas b/w field names and use it in the query. I know it's not the best way but just a quick fix.